# Best strategy for dealing with power interruption

Tags: filesystem

I'm trying to use Ubuntu 10.04/32 in an embedded environment with no keyboard attached. Power interruption is expected and happening quite often.
Right now I get a splashscreen requiring some keyboard input, if some ext3 partition gets corrupted. I need that to be handled automatically, without any user input.
What is the best strategy for dealing with this?

Comment: What error are you getting exactly?  Is it an actual file system error, or just the regular checks that occur after a given number of times the file system has been mounted?

Comment: It is an actual filesystem error, provoked deliberately by pulling the plug on system shutdown.

Comment: *Be sound, unmount!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the fstab entries to disable fsck:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>

UUID=blah       /               ext4    defaults        0       0
```

The important part is 'defaults 0 0' - that will mount it without doing checks and is the same on ext3.

For when you are able to do a managed upgrade (and need to do the diskcheck) simply:

```
sudo touch /forcefsck
```

That will force the fsck just the once on the next reboot.

Comment: I guess I will disable fsck and add a mainenance item in my app to check the filesystem on reboot once in a while.

Comment: The other thing is to leave those old kernel entries on the boot because sometimes they can magically rescue a failed, 'disk not recognized, down to Busybox level' boot situations.

Answer (score 1):

The best strategy is to prevent a disaster;

1. UPS (uninterruptible power supply) - keeps mission critical systems operational during main power supply outages.
2. Get Nut (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UPSwithNUT)
3. Test bench the solutions before using in a production/critical enviornment